# Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer in Swift button target

Tags: swift, function, uibutton, selector

i want to send parameter to my details func with selector but it does not work, how can i do this?

```
btnDetails.addTarget(self, action:#selector(goToDetailsFromMap(mid:id)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Short story: You can't send custom parameters.

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: Use a temporary variable like a property.

Comment: there is a loop, for example i have 5 views and they have own their id, in loop i set their buttonAction so if i use temporary variable, it is not work for all of them but thanks

Comment: Can you share your whole problem may be we can try to give some solution as you can't pass any custom parameters in selector method.

Comment: You can subclass uibutton and add a property on that or use delegate/protocol

Comment: Thanks, i figure out it. i create custombutton and added property:id and i send senderButton as parameters. and i take sender.id

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom button:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    var someId: Int?
    ...
}
```

Then in your viewController

```
    ...    
    btnDetails.someId = ...
    btnDetails.addTarget(self, action:#selector(didTapCustomButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    ...

@objc func didTapCustomButton(_ sender: CustomButton) {
    if let id = sender.someId {
        //Do something with id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding selector to button with code using **swift 5.0**

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(myButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

function declaration

```
 @objc func myButtonTapped() {
      //do stuff here
    }
```

Comment: i know this but i want to send params to myButtonTapped function. like view id

Comment: you can't send custom parameters.